# Smart TV development using TOAST or official SDK?

Tags: cordova, web-applications, tizen, webos, smart-tv

I have to develop a Smart TV application which needs to have the following components:

- Sign in page
- Retrieve data from external server
- Viewing webpages
- Preferably be developed with one code base

Now, Samsung does provide the possibility to develop a Smart TV application for both Samsung Tizen, Samsung Legacy and LG webOS with one code base by using [TOAST](https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/extension-libraries/toast). This sounds perfect for me, but the thing is that the last change to TOAST has been made [2 years ago](https://github.com/Samsung/cordova-plugin-toast).

Does someone advise against using TOAST and advise using the offical SDKs? Or is it still 'safe' to use TOAST? I asked the same question on the Samsung Developer forum and on Github, but haven't received an answer so far and couldn't find anything about it on the web. I've also mailed Samsung, but did not get a reply back.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is very close to asking for a recommendation for a tool or library, which is off topic. It's also very close to being opinion based, which is also off topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Samsung has very poor dev support. Their dev forums are awful and one-on-one support requests may lay dormant in the dashboard for indefinite amount of time. That's not an opinion but a fact.

Now if you plan to support Samsung Legacy and LG webOS then you better go with TOAST (not that I used it for anything), this way you might be sure that whatever you come up with will work there. Otherwise you can simply develop using any kind of framework that can be transpiled (through Babel) later to something that legacy browsers (and WebViews) are able to understand. That's what I did.